# Scrape special characters in Python Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, utf-8, beautifulsoup, ascii

How can I remove (or encode) the special characters from the page referenced below?

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

link = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/4281/000119312513062916/R2.htm"

request_headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5", "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "Referer": "http://google.com", "Connection": "keep-alive"}
request = urllib2.Request(link, headers=request_headers)
html = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
soup = soup.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
print(soup)
```

Comment: What's the actual problem? Why are you encoding the result before you print it? Stdout will be encoding to your terminal locale already.

Comment: I presume the issue is because you get an error parsing the html? The charset=us-ascii so there is no need to encode anything, the problem is the html is broken. You will need a different parser, html5lib and lxml manage to parse it but wit broken html who knows  how well.

Answer (score -1):

Unicode objects can only be printed if they can be converted to ASCII. If it can't be encoded in ASCII, you'll get that error. You probably want to explicitly encode it and then print the resulting soup:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

link = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/4281/000119312513062916/R2.htm"

request_headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5", "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "Referer": "http://google.com", "Connection": "keep-alive"}
reuest = requests.get(link, headers=request_headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reuest.text,"lxml")
print(soup.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: You've totally changed the OP's code with no explanation and yet kept the same erroneous encoding mechanism. The OP wants to use the `html.parser` for BS but you've quietly swapped if for `lxml`. Further, you've introduced the requests library, but is not necessary here. You're also wrong about Unicode objects - the stdout stream will try to encode to the shell's encoding. Rarely is that encoding ASCII. Therefore, you should allow stdout to encode as necessary and pass it `str` not `bytes`